# Understanding lifetimes for parameterized structs in Rust

Tags: rust, dereference, lifetime

The following code

```
struct Cat<'a, T> {
    coolness: &'a T,
}
```

complains saying

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
1 | struct Cat<'a, T> {
  |                - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'a`...
2 |     coolness: &'a T,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: ...so that the reference type `&'a T` does not outlive the data it points at
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     coolness: &'a T,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

With an explicit lifetime bound, it compiles. When I instantiate the struct where `T` is an `&i32` and despite each reference having a different lifetime, the code compiles. My understanding is that the compiler sees that the inner `&` outlives the outer `&`:

```
struct Cat<'a, T>
where
    T: 'a,
{
    coolness: &'a T,
}

fn main() {
    let b = 10;
    {
        let c = &b;
        {
            let fluffy = Cat { coolness: &c };
        }
    }
}
```

Does `Cat { coolness: &c }` expand to `Cat { coolness: &'a &'a i32 }`? Does the inner reference also assume the same lifetime and so forth for more nested references?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does `Cat { coolness: &c }` expand to `Cat { coolness: &'a &'a i32 }`?

Yes, the `Cat` ends up with a reference to a reference. This can be demonstrated by the following code compiling:

```
let fluffy = Cat { coolness: &c };
fn is_it_a_double_ref(_x: &Cat<&i32>) {}
is_it_a_double_ref(&fluffy);
```

However, the lifetime on each reference is not necessarily the same.

> My understanding is that the compiler sees that the inner & outlives the outer &

That's right. And this is precisely where the `T: 'a` bound comes into play.

Lifetime bounds are a bit tricky to understand at first. They put restrictions on the references contained in `T`. For example, given the bound `T: 'static`, types that don't contain any references, or only contain `'static` references, e.g. `i32` and `&'static str`, satisfy the bound, while types that contain non-`'static` references, e.g. `&'a i32`, don't, because `'a: 'static` is false. More generally, given the bound `T: 'a`, the type `T` satisfies the bound if, for every lifetime parameter `'x` on `T`, `'x: 'a` is true (types with no lifetime parameters trivially satisfy the bound).

Back to your code now. Let's give some names to these references. We'll say the type of `coolness` is `&'fluffy &'c i32`. `'c` is the lifetime of the variable `c` and `'fluffy` is the lifetime of the variable `fluffy` (counterintuitively, lifetimes encode the scope of a borrow, not the lifetime of the referent, although the compiler does check that the borrow doesn't extend beyond the referent's lifetime). That means the type of `Fluffy` is `Cat<'fluffy, &'c i32>`. Is it true that `&'c i32: 'fluffy`?

To check if `&'c i32: 'fluffy` is true, we need to check if `'c: 'fluffy` is true. `'c: 'fluffy` is true because the variable `c` goes out of scope after `fluffy`.